# Intellij "Find in Path" only has results for `Directory` but not Project, Module or Scope

Tags: intellij-idea

As shown in the screenshot the current file has multiple instances of `splice`. However the `Find in Path` dialog does not find even those ones - let alone the many instances in other project files.
[image]

I also tried the `Module` and `Scope` : none find anything.  However the `Directory` has the following:

[image]

So What is going on with the `In Project`, `Module` and `Scope` options?

Comment: The `In Project` scope does not include into search scope folders and files which are [**excluded**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/indexing.html#exclude) from the project. Where exactly is located the file in project?

Comment: Try also File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @Andrey Thx for the response.  There are several files in the shown directory `/git/cider.master/js`   I: did not add any files to `excluded` .

Comment: @Andrey  `Invalidate Caches/restart` had already been done: it had no effect.  Sometimes *none* of the options including `Directory` show anything. I have to resort to searching on command line. This is sad

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log (Help | Show Log in... action)? It would be great to have a reproducer project with steps and logs filled as YouTrack issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @Andrey Sure i'll do that straightaway

Comment: @Andrey  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @Andrey this is now being tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244685 .